# click sound on unpause SDL2 audio

Tags: c, audio, sdl-2

The first time I unpause SDL audio with `SDL_PauseAudio(0)`, immediately after initialisation with `SDL_OpenAudio()` I always get a click.

I've tried to handle this in my audio callback by ensuring that the amplitude of the sound ramps up from zero (and in fact for now I'm just using a sine wave, with phase starting at 0 so the wave form naturally begins at zero and ramps up) but this doesn't help.

Is there anything in particular I should be doing between calling `SDL_OpenAudio()` and `SDL_PauseAudio(0)` to prevent this click? I've struggled to find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this - nothing specific to SDL. Issue was in my callback code.

The issue was that I had switched from working with unsigned 16bit int format to signed 16bit int. In my callback I was calculating audio as double then converting to int format on output. 
When converting to unsigned that involved adding 1.0 to my (-1.0 to 1.0 range) signal to make it all positive rather than centered on 0. I just forgot to remove that +1.0 when I switched to signed audio - effectively my signal had a DC offset, which caused the discontinuity on init/close.

Without my posting callback and initialisation code there was little chance anybody could have guessed - and I'd thought my callback code was fine and this was a library usage issue.